# Matlab, SCIP and Opti Toolbox

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization, scip

I am using the Opti Toolbox, a free optimization toolbox for Matlab. I am solving a Mixed Integer Nonlinear Program, a MINLP. Inside the Opti Toolbox, the MINLP solver used is SCIP.

I define my own objective as a separate function (*fun* argument in Opti), and this function needs to call other matlab functions which take double arguments.

The problem is that whenever Opti invokes my function to evaluate the objective, it first calls it using a vector of '**scipvar**' objects and then it calls it again using a vector of '**double**' objects. My obj function does not work with the scipvar objects, it returns an error.

I tried (just for testing) setting the output of my function for something fixed when the type is '**scipvar**', and for the actual real thing when the type is '**double**', and this doesn't work, changing the fixed value actually changes the final optimal value.

I basically need to convert a scipvar object to double, is this possible? Or is there any other alternative?

Thank you.

Comment: If possible, could you please post your code?

Comment: The model is quite complex to build a simple example and post it here, but I now understand the problem, which I just answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after enlightenment by J. Currie, an Opti toolbox developer, I understood the cause of the problem above.

The first call to the objective with a vector of scipvar variables is actually a parser sweeping the objective function to see if it can be properly mapped to something that can be handled by SCIP. I reimplemented the objective function to use only methods allowed by scip - obtained by typing methods(scipvar) in matlab:

abs       dot       log       minus     mrdivide  norm      power     rdivide   sqrt      times
display   exp       log10     mpower    mtimes    plus      prod      scipvar   sum       uminus

Once the objective could be parsed by scip my problem worked fine.